# Why isn't $\mathcal{P}(^*A)\subseteq {^*}\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

I'm reading Goldblatt's *Lectures on the Hyperreals*, and he provides the following proof that $^*\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(^*A)$:

- Given sets $A,\mathcal{P}(A)\in\mathbb{U}$, the statement $\forall x\in\mathcal{P}(A):(\forall y\in x)(y\in A)$ is true if $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of $A$.
- Therefore $\forall x\in {^*}\mathcal{P}(A):(\forall y\in x)(y\in {^*}A)$ holds by transfer. So every element of $^*\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a subset of $^*A$.

If I understand correctly, transfer applies here because $\forall x \in X: Q(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x : x\in X \rightarrow Q(x)$, so the quantification is first order.

But I don't understand why we can't reverse this proof. I think $x\subseteq X $ is equivalent to $\forall y (y\in x \rightarrow y\in X)$ so even though the we're talking about subsets, it's still first order.
Then given $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $A$, the formula $\forall x (x\subseteq A \rightarrow x\in \mathcal{P}(A))$ is true.

What fails when this is transferred? Because $\forall x (x\subseteq {^*}A \rightarrow x\in {^*}\mathcal{P}(A))$ would mean that $\mathcal{P}(^*A)\subseteq ^*\mathcal{P}(A)$ which is false.

I'm not sure where my mistake is. I think I have a misunderstanding of how transfer works, and which statements are first order. It seems like the transferred $\forall y (y\in x \rightarrow y\in A)$ is going to miss some subsets of $^*A$, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that transfer only applies to formulas in the $\in$-language.  Your formula, as you acknowledge, is not a formula in the $\in$-language.   That's why transfer doesn't apply.  The simplest example is of course the subset $\mathbb N\subseteq {}^\ast\mathbb N$.  It is not an internal subset and therefore not an element of ${}^\ast\mathcal P$.

Comment: I think their question is why it isn’t in the $\in$ language given that you can express $\subset$ in terms of $\in$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, Well, let them try to express it in the $\in$-language, and see what they get. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. $x\subseteq X $ isn't in the $\in$-language, but what stops it being expressed in terms of membership like $\forall y (y\in x \rightarrow y\in X)$?

Comment: If you want to apply the transfer principle, you have to specify which set your variables range over.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! So the detail I was missing is that transfer only applies to bounded quantifiers.